# How many exceptions should I catch and what is the correct way to do it?

Tags: c#, exception

I want to get all the ip addresses of my computer. If something goes wrong (exception), I simply want empty string returned. Here is the function I use. `GetHostEntry` will throw several exceptions, and `GetHostName` also throws exception. How should I handle all these exceptions? Should I catch each of them one by one? That will make code cluttered.  Or Should I simply use `catch (Exception e)` and do nothing inside the `catch` block? What is the best way to handle it?

```
  private string GetIpAddress()
    {
        var temp = new StringBuilder();
        try {
                var hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
                var ips = from address in hostEntry.AddressList
                      where (address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                      select address;

                foreach (IPAddress ip in ips) {
                     temp.Append(ip).Append(" ");
                }
        } catch (exception1) {

        } catch (exception2) {

        } .....

        return temp.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels and OP:  It is perfectly acceptable to do nothing inside a Catch block as long as you limit the scope of the Try block.  Only ignore exceptions from code that you really don't care if it succeeds or not.  Sometimes "take no action" is the appropriate action to take.

Comment: Case in point... `BlockingCollection<T>.Take()` throws an `InvalidOperationException` when the collection is complete, and that's the *only* contract available to determine whether there are more items.  It's fine to have a `catch (InvalidOperationException) { }` in that case.  However, this is the *only* situation that comes to mind where I have used an empty catch block.

Answer (score 4):

You should catch a particular Exception if and only if you can do something useful about it.  Otherwise, let the Exception propagate to a level that can do something useful with it.

You should have a global exception handler that elegantly manages otherwise-uncaught exceptions gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to just throw away the exception, use an empty `catch`.

```
try
{
   // Code
}
catch {}
```

(Note that that's a pair of curly braces, not `()`'s)

Comment: `OutOfMemoryException`. `StackOverflowExcpetion`. Really?

Comment: @Oded: FWIW .NET doesn't allow you to catch StackOverflowException.

Comment: @oded those two cant be handled anyway... they will rethrow and dont always (if ever?) Trigger catch blocks at all...

Comment: @BrianRasmussen - True, but I was trying to make a point to the OP - swallowing all exceptions is a bad idea.

Comment: In the scenario posited in the question, where you expressly want to skip anything which fails *for any reason*, then this is the way to go.  There's no catchable exception which would make sense to handle separately or let bubble up.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, if you can't handle the exceptions, as evidenced when you have an empty catch block, then you should let them bubble up to the next level.

You should look at each exception that can be thrown and determine exactly why it could be thrown and what you should do about it.  For example, if DnsGetHostEntry() can throw an exception, why would it?  Should you return a host not found error?  Is there a sane default that you should return, that makes sense in your application?

Answer (score 1):

Handle the ones you can do something about, or that you want to handle in a specific way ( think failed to connect driving a message box to prompt whether or not youre connected to the network)

For other "its gone wrong" exceptions, let them propagate up to where we it is meaningful to handle it, or rethrow a meaningful, contextual exception and handle where it is appropriate.

If all youre tryng to do is send a report over a network of some process, to a log file, does it make sense to let that exception kill your process? Not really, so just wrap the top level call to SendNetworkReport.

If its central to your whole process, then let it propagate right up to your main control code, and abort the process in some contextually signifcant way.

Answer (score 0):

- Do not mute exceptions, at the very least write a log line. Even if you assume it's going to be a known kind of exception for a known reason.
- Don't catch an exception for no apparent reason - let it bubble up
- Do put try/catch on every *external* entry point - event handlers, threads etc. Exception that bubbles up from a button click handler will cause your app to crash, same goes for code on another thread or even on the same thread if forced to run on it (such as Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(delegate))
- Have the least amount of different handlers and *only* if you're actually treating the exceptions differently
- Add a listener to AppDomain.UnhandledException and log these too